# Azure DevOps CD pipeline using CMD

Tags: cmd, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2020

I'm now using Azure DevOps Server to implement a Azure DevOps CI/CD Pipeline(Using Command Line to perform the job in Release Pipeline) with Spring Boot Java Application.

If you are developing java application, you will know that you have to use `java -jar` to start the Application.

But I encountered a question is that when I use the command line to perform the `java -jar` command and put it in the Azure DevOps Release (CD) Pipeline, although the Application is already started and finished deployment

[image: Please look this picture: started and finished deployment]

The status will not turn to "completed". It will always be "Deploying".

[image: Please look this picture: Always be "Deploying]

Is there any solutions in cmd?
Supposed that I can only use CMD to do Release pipeline, I want to have a "Completed" stauts so that I can continue to next job.

Many thanks!!

Comment: When you run the `java -jar` in your local machine, will it stuck at the start info? You could try to add `exit 0` in your cmd command and check it it could work.

Comment: What do you mean for adding `exit 0` ?

Comment: This method is used to check if the previous command has completed. Adding exit 0 will exit the command line task and move to the next task

Comment: But as I said, how can I check whether the cmd command is done or not?

Comment: It might be something like that:
```if log.contains(Started Application)
then exit 0```
but how can I check the command is done or not? I have totally no idea tho...
?

Comment: On your local machine, when you execute the java -jar , you could check if you could input additional command in new line. In azure Devops, you could directly add exit 0 after the java -jar. Then you could check if the command line task will finished.

Comment: I tried, but nothing change. Also that couldn't check the deployment is succeed or failed, that gonna be a problem tho.

Comment: When you run the command on your local machine, will it stuck at the same step？